SUM function in SubQuery using Group By
I have a table that stores data for invoices for my various suppliers. I am trying to write a query to determine which supplier I have spent the most money on, so I have currently written a query that gets the sum of the InvoiceTotals while grouping by the SupplierID. The part that is tripping me up is that I need to account for the InvoiceType - if it's 'credit' the InvoiceTotal for that one is actually negative (so it should be subtracted). The CurrentStatus should only be 'Paid' too.
For example, in the table below I would expect SUP-2 to be returned as the highest amount, with a total of 700.00.



ID
SupplierID
InvoiceTotal
InvoiceType
CurrentStatus




1
'SUP-1'
1200.00
'Debit'
'Paid'


2
'SUP-1'
600.00
'Credit'
'Paid'


3
'SUP-2'
400.00
'Debit'
'Paid'


4
'SUP-2'
300.00
'Debit'
'Paid'


5
'SUP-3'
20000.00
'Credit'
'Paid'


6
'SUP-4'
30000.00
'Debit'
'Unpaid'



I initially created the following query, which just sums all the totals and groups by the supplier, but it doesn't account for the credits/negatives:
SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal), SupplierID FROM Supplier_Invoices WHERE CurrentStatus IN ('Paid') GROUP BY SupplierID
I tried to SUM the negative/credits separately and subtract them from the SUM of the Debits but the TotalAmts are all showing up as NULL for some reason on all of them (if I remove the TOP 1 I can see the whole table):
SELECT TOP 1
       ((SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
         FROM Supplier_Invoices m
         WHERE CurrentStatus IN ('Paid')
           AND InvoiceType != 'CREDIT'
           AND m.SupplierID = t.SupplierID) -
        (SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal)
         FROM Supplier_Invoices h
         WHERE CurrentStatus IN ('Paid')
           AND InvoiceType = 'CREDIT'
           AND h.SupplierID = t.SupplierID)) AS TotalAmt,
       t.SupplierID
FROM Supplier_Invoices t
WHERE CurrentStatus IN ('Paid')
GROUP BY SupplierID
ORDER BY TotalAmt desc

How can I correctly return the supplier with the highest InvoiceTotal while accounting for the fact that some of the invoiceTotal's are negatives if they are credit? I feel like there should be a much better way to do it then I am currently attempting.

It looks to me like the text "Credit" and "Debit" is being used instead of allowing negative numbers in the InvoiceTotal column. Would it make things simpler if you showed "Credit" or "Debit" in the user interface, depending on if the total was greater than or less than zero, and removed the "InvoiceType" column?

SELECT top 1 
        SupplierID,
        SUM(InvoiceTotal * IIF(InvoiceType = 'Debit', 1, -1)) AS Suplier_total,
        rnk = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(InvoiceTotal * IIF(InvoiceType = 'Debit', 1, -1)) DESC)
    FROM Supplier_Invoices 
    WHERE CurrentStatus = 'PAID' 
    GROUP BY SupplierID
    ORDER BY rnk

Here the subquery just multiplies the amount by 1 or -1 depending on the invoice type, then ranks the results, then finally selects the top 1 value
Here it is in action using your sample data
https://dbfiddle.uk/BQpKgQa5

Interesting solution. Please explain the benefit of rnk calculation. Doesn't ORDER BY Suplier_total desc work just as well?

You are correct, that would have worked and would have been simpler. I think I started with the notion of returning several values based on the rank using a subquery and then changed my mind half way thru! Too much work and too much heat.. :)

This solution performs the sum on a case expression. If you need a 3rd Invoice type like 'Correction' this would be the easiest solution to apply.
SELECT TOP 1 
        SupplierID, 
        SUM(CASE InvoiceType 
            WHEN 'Debit' THEN InvoiceTotal
            WHEN 'Credit' THEN -InvoiceTotal
            Else 0 END) as SumTotal    
FROM Supplier_Invoices
WHERE   CurrentStatus='Paid'
GROUP BY SupplierID
ORDER BY SumTotal desc

fiddle
Before filtering:



SupplierID
SumTotal




SUP-1
600


SUP-2
700


SUP-3
-20000



After sorting and TOP 1



SupplierID
SumTotal




SUP-2
700




The following is, I think, very clear
SELECT TOP(1) SupplierID, SUM(IIF(InvoiceType='Credit',-1.0,1.0) *InvoiceTotal) AS SumTotal
FROM #Supplier_Invoices 
WHERE CurrentStatus = 'Paid' 
GROUP BY SupplierID
ORDER BY 2 DESC


Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal

You can try to manipulate the data before aggregating.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SupplierID
        , (
            CASE InvoiceType
                WHEN 'Credit' THEN -InvoiceTotal
                ELSE InvoiceTotal
            END
        ) AS InvoiceTotal
    FROM Supplier_Invoices
    WHERE CurrentStatus = 'Paid'
)
SELECT SupplierID, SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS TotalAmt
FROM cte
GROUP BY SupplierID
ORDER BY TotalAmt DESC

